# Unicode character does not show when entered using <C-q> with cp932

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, unicode

I am trying to get the  unicode character '①' inserted in vim with the insert mode command but failed.

```
<CTRL-Q>u2460 --> result:$`
```

So I copied the unicode to vim and checked the hex value using `ga` to find the value as '8740'. I re-entered the unicode codepoint using the determined hex value to get the character successfully.

```
<CTRL-Q>u8740 --> result:①
```

But I don't understand why the codepoint '2460' does not work.

I am using windows 7. `set encoding?` gives me `cp932`.

Comment: Which platform are you on? And what does `:set encoding?` give?

Comment: Its a system working on Windows 7. Encoding is cp932.

Comment: Try using utf-8 if possible; while Vim works with many encodings, I've found that it supports utf-8 best.